# Download manager that can continue download

Tags: download-manager

I have a file half-downloaded. Do you know a download manager that can continue the download without loading the part I already loaded? Is this possible with HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

check out [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) command line which is built into Windows.